# Unable to find etter.dns file in the directory /usr/share/ettercap/ in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I am using Ettercap on Kali Linux version 2017.3 on vmware. I am unable to find the etter.dns file in the directory where it should be present, which is /usr/share/ettercap/. Instead of etter.dns, etter.dns.save file is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
find / -name etter.dns
```

Mine is in

```
/etc/ettercap/
```

If you don't have basic command line skills then you are going to struggle with Kali, or with any linux distro where you need to use the CLI.